# Better to have one master table or split into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am creating a database and I am unsure of the best way to design my tables.  I have a table of real estate properties and I want to store information about those properties - e.g. bedrooms, bathrooms, size...  I may have additional information I want to store in the future if it seems useful - e.g. last purchase price or date built, so I need to be flexible to make additions.

Is it better to create a separate table for each "characteristic" or to have one table of all the characteristics? It seems cleaner to separate the characteristics, but easier programming-wise to have one table.

> CHARACTERISTIC TABLE

```
id  property_id  characteristic  value
1   1            bedrooms        3
2   1            bathrooms       2
3   1            square feet     1000
4   2            bedrooms        2
...
```

OR

> BEDROOM TABLE

```
id  property_id  bedrooms
1   1            3
2   2            2
...
```

> BATHROOM TABLE

```
id  property_id  bathrooms
1   1            2
...
```

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, my knowledge of database design is pretty basic.

Comment: One table seems right for this (id serves no useful purpose here)

Comment: However, when using an eav model, I like to split attributes by data type, so integer type things go in one table, and date type things go in another table, etc,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a middle ground between your two suggestions.   Off the cuff I would do

property table  (UID address zip other unique identifying properties)

Rooms table ( UID, propertyID, room type , room size,floor, shape, color, finish, other roo  specific details ect..)

Property details (uid, propertyID, lot size, school district, how cost, tax rate, other entire property details)

Finally a table or two for histories eg.

Property sales history(UID, PropertyID , salesdate, saleprice, sale reason, ect..)

Often grouping your data by just "does it match" logic can yield you good results....  care needs only be taken to account for 1to1 and 1tomany relationship needs of tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am focused to this:

> "I have a table of real estate properties"

Now as far as i knew you has to be a different type of:

```
Houses
Bedrooms
Comfort room and so on.
```

For further explanation:
You has to be a table of:

```
1. House type
2. House names,description,housetypeid,priceid,bedroomid,roofid,comfortroomid and any other that related to your house.
3. Bedroom type
4. Comfort room type
5. Dining type
6. roof type if it has.
7. House prices
8. Bathroom type
```

something like that.

Comment: Even wall type if it has.

Answer (score 0):

One table with a few columns:

Columns for price, #br, #bath, FR, DR, sqft and a small number of other *commonly* checked attributes.  Then one JSON column with all the other info (2 dishwashers, spa, ocean view, etc).

Use `WHERE` clause for the separate columns, then finish the filtering in you client code, which can more easily look into the JSON.